# When copying and pasting images, is all the quality maintained?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, adobe-photoshop, copy-paste

When copying and pasting is 100% of the data maintained? For example In Firefox, on Windows, when copying an image and pasting it into Photoshop, is the quality the same then if you did the long way and saved the image and reopened it in Photoshop?

Comment: When you perform a copy of a file a new copy of the file is create identical to the original.  It can even have the same filename if its not in the same folder.

Comment: I do believe some quality is lost because Windows re-encodes it ...hence the famous JPEG pixelation issues that arise from it being copy/pasted from different sources.

Comment: How do you go about 'copying' the image from Firefox into Photoshop without first saving the image? I mean, are you using an extension in Firefox to grab the image data or are you just using the `Print Screen` functionality of Windows? If it's the later, then yes, you could lose data since Windows encodes the screen capture in a different format than what the image itself might be ..

Comment: My understanding is that it depends on the nature of the source.  A full size image can be embedded and displayed at a smaller size.  I've experienced it both ways.  Right-clicking the image sometimes copies the original, full resolution image, and sometimes just the rendering on the page.  You may need to try it and see what you get on a case by case basis.

Comment: @NathanC: There's no quality loss while simply copy pasting. The loss occurs only when saving using a lossy format.

Comment: @txtechhelp I right click and select "copy image"

Comment: @txtechhelp does it matter?

Comment: @Celeritas, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of image and the data contained within it, but looking at [the source code](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c2a414f8bd73/widget/windows/nsImageClipboard.cpp) that handles the "Copy Image" functionality on Windows as well as looking at how the [Windows clipboard API works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is a conversion done on the data to put it on the Windows clipboard, more specifically, Firefox puts the image into a BMP [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) (via this line of code `nsCOMPtr<imgIEncoder> encoder = do_CreateInstance("@mozilla.org/image/encoder;2?type=image/bmp", &rv);`, and while they support the DIBV5 format (which gives more color space and alpha information), I suspect there's a bug elsewhere or the encoding need be changed in the code to support more formats (like GIF/PNG with transparency). As it turns out the transparency loss has been a [known](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=249032) [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722555#c30) for some time now without resolve.

So while you might not see image quality degrade for most of the images on the web, to answer more directly: no, 100% of the data is **not** maintained when you do a "Copy Image" vs. "Save Image As.." (especially for image types with transparency).

I hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there is no compression on the clipboard.

How ever in some cases, you can loose the quality like screenshot, some image format or bugs like [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384116)

Tools like [Clipx](http://clipx.org/) could help

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a file using the operating system there is no recompression and no further loss. That is because you are copying the whole thing and not doing any processing on it.

On the other hand, if you load the image file into an editor and then save, you **will** loose something *unless* you are using a lossless format.

So when you copy a file into the Windows clipboard, you *should* be copying all of the data without interpretation and should not loose anything. Of course, when you then save the file, you *will* loose something at that point.

This really only applies to JPEG files and not normally to GIF or PNG since they will generally be treated in a lossless way unless some other optimisation is applied.

Comment: Regarding GIF/PNG one important thing to keep in mind is that depending on the image editor used transparency and alpha channels can be lost.

Comment: Thanks @Karan, that is true. Of course, if you come across such a tool, I would recommend getting rid of it! It is also worth checking if your image editor correctly handles *any* metadata which is also easily lost.

Comment: Well, Paint for one is commonly used even though we know how limited it is. :)

Comment: Urgh! Indeed, makes me shudder when I see someone using it, especially at work.